# Accessing modules in Rails lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

There are probably hundreds of these questions on here but I haven't been able to get one to work yet.  I'm using Rails 6 and I always have trouble writing custom modules.

I have a file for creating email tokens: `lib/account_management/email_token.rb`

```
module AccountManagement
  module EmailToken
    def create_email_token(user)
       ....
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my controller I have tried all kinds of things:
`require 'account_management/email_token'`
`include AccountManagement::EmailToken`
Calling it with:   `create_and_send_email_token(user)`

At one point I added `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib/account_management/')` but I didn't think you still had to do that.

Whenever I try to call the controller action I get one of a few error messages:

```
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Accounts::SessionsController::EmailToken
#this happens if I try to manually send through the rails console 
(although inside of a byebug I can call require 'account_management/email_token' and it returns
true.
```

Most commonly I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `create_email_token' for #<Accounts::SessionsController:0x00007ffe8dea21d8>
Did you mean?  create_email):
# this is the name of the controller method and is unrleated.
```

Comment: In which line you have included the module in your controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is by placing your files in `app/lib/account_management/email_token.rb`. Rails already autoloads any subdirectory of the app folder*.

`/lib` has not been on the autoload paths since Rails 3. If you want to add it to the autoload paths you need to add `/lib` not `/lib/account_management` to the autoload/eager loading paths. In Zeitwerk terms this adds a root where Zeitwerk will index and resolve constants from.

```
config.autoload_paths += config.root.join('lib')
config.eager_load_paths += config.root.join('lib')
```

Note that eager_load_paths is only used when eager loading is turned on. Its turned off by default in development to enable code reloading.

`/lib` is added to `$LOAD_PATH`so you can also manually require the file with:

```
require 'account_management/email_token'
```

See:

- [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#eager-loading)
- [Rails #37835](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37835)

Comment: * Spring and other preloaders sometimes get "stuck" and don't recognize newly added folders. The solutions is to stop spring with `spring stop` - it will restart the next time Rails boots.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.  It seems like adding a `lib` folder to `app` is the way to go to avoid hassles with turning eager loading off in development.

Comment: In Rails 6+, it would be `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`,
    `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`